# Why is my Python script printing "None" after using a function and using input(print())?

Tags: python, function, input, printing

This is my code:

```
def videoConv(sourceDir, targetDir):
videoSourceDeclaration(sourceDir, targetDir)
input(print("\nis this correct?\n[y]/[n] (yes or no): "))
```

which prints this:

```
is this correct?
[y]/[n] (yes or no):
None
```

How can I stop it from printing "None"? I've read that I should use *return*, but I'm not really sure what I should do.

Also, this is the whole videoSourceDeclaration function:

```
def videoSourceDeclaration(sourceDir, targetDir):
sourceDir = input("Input source directory (leave blank for default): ")
os.system('cls||clear')
os.chdir("..")
print("source directory: " + os.getcwd())
targetDir = input("\nInput target directory (leave blank for default): ")
if targetDir == "":
    if platform == "linux":
        targetDir = ("~\\videos")
        # not sure of the linux dir, change later and add macos")
    elif platform == "win32":
        targetDir = ("c:\\" + "users\\" + getpass.getuser() + "\\" + "videos")
if targetDir == ("~\\videos") or ("c:\\" + "users\\" + getpass.getuser() + "\\" + "videos"):
    isTargetDirDefault = True   
    os.system('cls||clear')
print("source directory: " + os.getcwd() + "\ntarget directory: " + targetDir)
```

Comment: `input(print("blah blah blah"))` is incorrect syntax. If you want text to be printed as part of the input prompt, just use `input("blah blah blah")` instead.

Comment: Input already prints the string. Your script actually prints from ```print```, and then input prints the result of ```print``` which is ```None```. Hence, you can just delete the call to ```print```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a few things here.

In order for you to print the input of the user, you must first get it. You did it correctly with the `input()` function, but this will return you the result. That's what you need to print.

So you should change your code from this:

`input(print("\nis this correct?\n[y]/[n] (yes or no): "))`

to this

`print(input("\nis this correct?\n[y]/[n] (yes or no): "))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, although MattDMo's comment seems like an even better solution. Are your answers basically the same thing or do they have a difference?

Comment: Hi, yes, MattDMo's solution will print the text correctly, but will not print the input of the user.